# I have a reactjs app that won't work in IE anyone know why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, browser

the error I get in the IE console is "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app".

Update: issue was that IE does not support index.find so it wasn't rendering the scripts

Comment: Its disabled in the IE settings. [How to inable JS on IE](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/internet-explorer)

Answer (score 4):

These steps are extracted from the provided link.

1. Select the Gear in the upper-right corner of the screen or the “Tools” menu if you have the menu bar enabled, then select “Internet Options“.
2. Select the “Security” tab.
3. Select the zone you wish to modify. In most cases, it will be “Internet“.
4. Select the “Custom level…” button.
5. Scroll down to the “Scripting” area and select the radio button to “Enable” or “Disable” it “Active scripting“. You may also opt for IE11 to “Prompt” you to allow

Please take a look [here](https://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-enabledisable-javascript) for detailed instructions how to enable Javascript on IE.

Comment: Don't provide an answer with just an external link. This is best suited for comments as its not really a coding problem.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with some content. I have changed my vote. Tough I still think a comment would have sufficed as the OP should have googled the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I had already tried these steps turns out it was a coding issue and the IE wouldn't work with the index.find functions so it wasn't rendering the script